# Android O (26) change color of text and widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-8.0-oreo

I test my app with Android O (api level 26) and I see a difference about the text color and widget like `Checkbox`. It's like it's disabled.

Is there any new parameter that set this color? Something like `accentColor`? I don't find anything in [Android O Features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html).

**Android 25:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Android 26:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: put your styles here to better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after changing one by one each style attributes. I found the one that create the issue with Android O. I just change its value and that's good!

```
<item name="android:colorForeground">#cacaca</item>
```

I think that with API level `>=26`, this attribute is used by the widgets to set the color.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the context you are using is an Application context and so does not have a theme. Create and use this context instead:

```
new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId)
```